# Not able to initialise a model from JSONModel. I am getting nil value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

I am not able to initialise a model from JSONModel. I am using [JSONModel](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel) (as after this poc the .json is huge and needs a third party library like this to take care.). My steps are as follows:

1. Pod installed the JSONModel
2. Create a simple model that you want the .json got from the url to initialise
   your model in your project.
3. As per the description I am getting the `nil` value out of it.

   Analysing why I got the `nil` value, I think one might be the reason.

   ```
   if (!json || ![json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) 
     return nil;
   ```

here I am getting .json value, so checking this

```
[json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]],
```

I am getting a `nil` value .

In .h file of my model. I create a property of jokeid, text and in .m file I am using this code

```
+(JSONKeyMapper*)keyMapper{
    return [[JSONKeyMapper alloc]initWithModelToJSONDictionary:@{@"jokeid":@"jokeid", @"text":@"text"}];

}
```

I need some guidance in this "arrayOfModelsFromData:" of JSONModel . I am posting my snapshot and the code

code is in [github](https://github.com/utsav475908/sdfs) https://github.com/utsav475908/sdfs 
Debugging snapshot is here [image]

Comment: Can you show the entire "jsonDict" and structure you have for JokeModel. Reason being is that jsonModel matches the data to your property and its datatype. If it cannot be match it will return you with an empty object.

Comment: Yes, I have given the link of the github. To answer your question , jsonDict is like this : {
    jokeid = 7;
    text = "There used to be a street named after Chuck Norris but it was changed because nobody crosses Chuck Norris and lives";
}

Comment: The github goes to Jsonmodel library page. Not ur code. zzz

Comment: github https://github.com/utsav475908/sdfs               is the link to my code

Comment: #GeneCode can you help me , why I am getting nil value.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a nil value because your JSON object contains a dictionary, not an array.

For correct work try to change your json payload to something like this:

```
[
     {
     "jokeid": 1,
     "text": "There used to be a street named after Chuck Norris but it was changed because nobody crosses Chuck Norris and lives"
     },
     {
     "jokeid": 2,
     "text": "There used to be a street named after Chuck Norris but it was changed because nobody crosses Chuck Norris and lives"
     },
     {
     "jokeid": 3,
     "text": "There used to be a street named after Chuck Norris but it was changed because nobody crosses Chuck Norris and lives"
     },
     {
     "jokeid": 4,
     "text": "There used to be a street named after Chuck Norris but it was changed because nobody crosses Chuck Norris and lives"
     },
]
```

and you will receive an array with 4 objects.
[image: Screenshot]